# conda pack multiple environments

Tags: python, docker, conda

I am trying to shrink a docker image used for one of our continuous integration (CI) setups.

I've had good luck using "[Shrink your Conda Docker images with conda-pack](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/conda-docker-image-size/)", but only for a single conda environment.

Is there a way to use `conda-pack` and `conda-unpack` for several environments?  Or somehow reconstruct a working conda with multiple environments?  I'd like to let the scripts in the CI use `conda run -n some_env command` or `conda activate some_env`.

Small example:

**Dockerfile**

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.0-experimental

# build-stage image:
FROM continuumio/miniconda3 AS build
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN conda install conda-pack
RUN for v in 3.7 3.8; \
  do \
    p=py${v//\./} && \
    conda create -n $p python=$v && \
    conda install -n $p conda-build && \
    conda-pack -n $p -o /tmp/env.tar && \
    mkdir -p /venv/$p && \
      (cd /venv/$p && tar xf /tmp/env.tar && rm /tmp/env.tar) && \
    /venv/$p/bin/conda-unpack; \
  done

# runtime-stage image
FROM amazonlinux:latest as runtime
CMD [ "/bin/bash" ]
COPY --from=build /venv /venv

# our base will be py38, but we'll have the others as well
RUN source /venv/py38/bin/activate && conda init
```

Then, after `docker build -t test .`:

```sh
docker run -it test

(base) bash-4.2# python --version
Python 3.8.8
(base) bash-4.2# conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /venv/py38

(base) bash-4.2# source /venv/py37/bin/activate 
(py37) bash-4.2# python --version
Python 3.7.10
(py37) bash-4.2# conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                     /venv/py38
```

So, we do have `/venv/py38` and `/venv/py37`, and they are usable (via `source /venv/pyXX/activate`), but they are not `conda` environment "siblings". It's either one or the other, and we cannot use `conda activate pyXX` to switch from one to the other.

Is there a way to use `conda-pack` and `conda-unpack` in such a way that all environments are recognized by a "master" `conda`?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I am now also interested in using conda-pack to tar two conda environments as one and later alternatively activate both. Something like conda activate /path/to/Env/first and conda activate /path/to/Env/second after conda-unpack.